# Openfire xmpp server error while configure remote mysql db

Tags: xmpp

Recently i am preparing my xmpp sever (openfire) for clustering. that's why i need to setup more then one openfire server using the same DB.
and when configure database while setting up openfire server using a remote ip; i got a error as :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.DefaultConnectionBuilder.buildConnection(DefaultConnectionBuilder.java:39)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.Prototyper.buildConnection(Prototyper.java:159)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.Prototyper.sweep(Prototyper.java:102)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.PrototyperThread.run(PrototyperThread.java:44)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.j
```

**please correct me if i am doing something wrong ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First grant all privilege to your remote mysql user. To do this You need to follow these steps

## Steps to grant remote login privilege

Run command

1. sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. make comment this line :-  bind-address = 127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0 and exit.
3. login in mysql and run command
       GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
4. exit from mysql and run command
       sudo service mysql restart
5. to check remote login access login at this DB from your local server by using commond
       mysql -uroot -p -h IP

** if  login success it means remote login access granted.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a networking / configuration issue: Connection refused means that the server cannot connect to your database.

It could be because the database port is not exposed or is different than the default. Most likely, the DNS / naming of the machine are possibly incorrect.